# Использование библиотеки с Apache 2.0 лицензией в проекте с MIT (Expat) лицензией

Tags: лицензирование

Здравствуйте! Я в своём проекте использую библиотеку с Apache 2.0 лицензией.
По условиям Apache 2.0 лицензии, я должен в корне своего проекта создать файлик LICENSE с указанием текста лицензии Apache 2.0 и файл NOTICE, перечисляющий все библиотеки, лицензированные под лицензией Apache вместе с именами их создателей.
Но в то же время мне в файле LICENSE надо указать текст лицензии MIT (Expat). Как его объединить с текстом лицензии Apache 2.0 ? Не знаете ли вы проекта с подобной ситуацией, чтоб можно было посмотреть и понять?

А ещё интересует ситуация, когда кто-то возьмет этот мой проект, о котором я говорю, и использует в своём MIT-проекте. Нужно ли ему копировать все те файлы для Apache 2.0 в корень своего проекта, или нет? Ведь по идее, он использует в своём MIT проекте другой MIT проект, а не другой Apache 2.0 проект, по этому ему всё это делать не надо, правильно? Или я ошибаюсь?